# c++ template specialization of template container

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

what i would do is like ...

```
template < template <typename ... > typename __Container, typename ... __Args >
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, __Container<__Args ...> const& rhs){
  stringstream ss;
  int i = 0;
  for (const auto& it : rhs) 
    ss << "idx[" << i << "] " << it << "\n";
  return os << ss.str();
}

/// 
/// ... and something template specialization code
/// 

int main (){
  std::vector<int> vec_data = { ... };
  std::cout << vec_data << std::endl; 

  std::deque<int> dq_data = { ... };
  std::cout << dq_data << std::endl; 

  std::map<std::string, double> map_data = { {}, {}, {}, ... };
  std::cout << map_data << std::endl; 


  return 0;
}
```

in this example, deque and vector are not a problem, but when i tried to struggle to specialize std::map i dumped it. is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: what is the meaning of "i dumped it" ?

Comment: For `std::map`, you have to print `std::pair<const Key, Value>`.

Comment: `__Container` is reserved identifier. Avoid double underscores...

Comment: cannot reproduce. fails also without the map https://godbolt.org/z/fYdx54bhG

Comment: I recommend to not write catch-em-all `operator<<` templates. You can get the same from a `print(const Container&)` function template.

Comment: template operator with no user types are dangerous (susceptible of ODR (in future)).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number im sorry for my poor english. something... stumble? failed? whatever i failed for it

Comment: @Jarod42 what is `__Container` reserved for? like preprocessor? can i see something for it ?

Comment: For compiler builtins and the standard library, basically. Here: http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3

Comment: ok but how did it fail? You do not need to explain a lot if you just post a [mcve] and the compiler error message

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks man, i will read it in weekend patiently.

Answer (score 1):

Function templates can't be partially specialized, but can be overloaded:

```
template <typename ...P>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::map<P...> &map)
```

But it's not the best idea, because you'd also have to specialize for `std::multimap` and `std::unordered_[multi]map`, and any non-standard containers you encounter in the future.

Instead you could create a function to print the single element, and overload it for `std::pair` (which is the element type of maps). Then call it from your operator.

There are more problems with the code:

- Operators should only be overloaded where [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) can find them. Otherwise you won't be able to call them from some places (from any namespace that defines any `operator<<`; or from a template function defined above your operator).

  Since the only suitable namespace here would be `std`, and adding declarations there is not allowed, you shouldn't create such operator in the first place. Write a function instead.
- Identifiers containing `__` or starting with `_[A-Z]` are reserved, don't use them.
- The `operator<<` should accept any `basic_ostream<...>` to support wide streams.
- `stringstream` should be `ostringstream`, or removed altogether (print directly to the ostream).

Comment: thanks a lot! in third thing you mean if i have to override `operator<<`, i should replace `std::ostream` as `basic_ostream<...>`, right?

Comment: @JadeKim Yep, it should be something like `std::basic_ostream<Q...>`, where `Q` is an extra template parameter `typename ...Q` you add to your `operator<<` (or function, if you replace it with a function).